# TypeScript how to write this more pragmatic?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Can I write this code more pragmatic somehow (mainly the RenderMenu I want to improve, but suggestions on both is appreciated)? I can't really think of how. I'm not used to TypeScript. I'm rendering a food-menu from JSON (import {data} from './DinnerData'. First I render the title e.g. "Starters" then it goes through all the starters and rendering each dinner with two map functions.

```
export const RenderMenu = (props: Props) => {
    return (
        <>
            {data.types.map((type, index) => {
                return (
                    <>
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="col-xl-12">
                                <div className="section-title text-center">
                                    <h4 key={index}>
                                        {type.name}
                                    </h4>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div className="row menu_style1">
                            {type.items.map((item, index) => {
                                return (
                                    <>
                                        <Dinner title={item.name} price={item.price} children={item.text} image={"https://i.imgur.com/kbpceNv.jpg"} />
                                    </>
                                )
                            })}
                        </div>
                    </>
                )
            })}
        </>
    );

};
```

Here is the Menu itself.

```
export const Menu = (props: Props) => {

   return (
      <>
         <section className="about-area pt-60 m-2 p-2" id="home">
            <div className="container mb-5">
               <div className="row">
                  <div className="col-xl-12 mb-60">
                     <div className="section-title text-center">
                        <p></p>
                        <h1>Vår meny</h1>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>

               <RenderMenu/>
            </div>
         </section>

      </>
   );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extract smaller components.

**MenuTitle**

```
export const MenuTitle = (props) => {
  const { name, key } = props;
  return (
    <div className="row">
      <div className="col-xl-12">
        <div className="section-title text-center">
          <h4 key={key}>{name}</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

**MenuItems**

```
export const MenuItems = (props) => {
  const { items } = props;
  return (
    <div className="row menu_style1">
      {items.map((item, index) => {
        <>
          <Dinner
            title={item.name}
            price={item.price}
            children={item.text}
            image={"https://i.imgur.com/kbpceNv.jpg"}
          />
        </>;
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
```

RenderMenu is now more cleaner & easier on the head.

```
export const RenderMenu = (props) => {
  return (
    <>
      {data.types.map((type, index) => {
        return (
          <>
            <MenuTitle name={type.name} key={index} />
            <MenuItems items={type.items} />
          </>
        );
      })}
    </>
  );
};
```